# NodeJS FileAppend Error: EPERM Operation not permitted, write

Tags: node.js, file, append

NodeJS FileAppend Error: EPERM Operation not permitted, write

Node v4.3.1

I am a developer on a Couchbase/AngularJS/Express.js/Node.JS application.  The application current state is the beginning of User Testing.  My user found an issue with creation of a flat file from data stored within CouchBase.  Due to the size of the data and the method of storage used, I need to retrieve the data in groups.  Each group (JSON document) contains up to 50,000 rows.  I have a process, which will retrieve the groups.  The NodeJS will generate the rows from the retrieved group then write the group to a file.  When I set up the process to write the individual groups, the process works fine but the user wants the data in a single file.  Due to limitation of space on the server, I cannot increase the memory allocation to process all groups into the single file to write.  I attempted to use the appendFile and writeFile with append flag methods but the process fails.  I receive the following error message:
    { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, write] errno: -4048, code: 'EPERM', syscall: 'write' }

During the testing to correct the issue, I was able to append the file to my local C: drive.  When I try to append to my network drive, I receive the error message.  I contacted the system administration to verify the permission.  All the permissions are enabled including the special permission to create folders/append data.

I do not understand why I can append data to my local drive but not a network location.

To help with the issue, listed below you will find a code snippet illustrating my attempts:

```
function writeExpFile(fileName, writeDirectory, writeExFile, callback) {
    //fs.writeFile(writeDirectory + '\\' + fileName, writeExFile.toString(), {encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'a'}, function(err, result)
    fs.appendFile(writeDirectory + '\\' + fileName, writeExFile.toString(), { encoding: 'utf8' }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('FMwriteFile', err);
            callback(err, null);
        }
        else {
            console.log('writeDirectory done', writeDirectory + '\\' + fileName + ' ' + cntWEF.toString());
            callback(null, result);
        }
    });

    //fs.appendFileSync(writeDirectory + '\\' + fileName, writeExFile.toString(), {encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'a'});
    //fs.writeFileSync(writeDirectory + '\\' + fileName, writeExFile.toString(), {encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'a'});
    //console.log('writeDirectory done', writeDirectory + '\\' + fileName + ' ' + cntWEF.toString());
    //callback(null, 'success');
};
```

Where `filename` is the name of file (file1), `writeDirectory` is the name of the folder path (\server\folder1\folder1a\folder1aa), and `writeExFile`is the data to be written.

I hope to find a person(s) that can explain why this process fails to my network drive but is successful to my local drive.  In addition, provide a method to resolve this issue.

I appreciate all suggestions.

Comment: What operating system(s) are you using?

Comment: windows 7.  As for the servers, i do not know.

Comment: Have you tried running your code as root?

Comment: code runs fine to my C:\ drive and all directories associated but as soon as I attempt to run it to a network drive using DNC format. I recieve the error.  The only method I have not tried is to replace the server specification with a drive letter.

Comment: the error you are getting likely means that you are  going to need to run your code as root

Comment: I will need to try that but I do not believe I would not be able to because this process will be initiated via a command from a webpage.  I have gotten around the issue by opening a write stream, writing all the records then ending the write stream to flush the write buffer.